# is perceptron based implementation of Logical conjunction (AND) regression or classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

A perceptron model could be used to implement a Logical conjunction (AND) operator.

In this case, is the problem regression or classification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AND operator gives you answer of True or False, it is binary in nature.

Hence, it is classification in nature.